# Either possible? 1) Connection to Oracle 8i w/ ojdbc5 or ojdbc6 2) Multiple ojdbc jars

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle8i

I'm building an application which is collating data from multiple data sources.  Of these data sources, we have multiple instances of Oracle running.

I find that the only way I can connect to my Oracle 8i instance is by using the *ojdbc14.jar* and the following:

```
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$HOST)(PORT=$PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$SID)))"
Class.forName(driver);
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, $USER, $PASSWORD);
c.close();
```

When I try to update to *ojdbc5.jar* or *ojdbc6.jar*, using the same code, I get an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException.  Ditto if I use just the URL "jdbc:oracle:thin:$user/$password@$host:$port:$sid", which does work against the more recent Oracle instances I'm connecting to.

I'd rather not get locked into having to use the older *ojdbc14.jar* (especially as I'm using Java 6) as I might have to support higher Oracle databases quite soon in the future.

So, I'm hoping one of two scenarios is possible:

1) There's a connection string I'm simply overlooking which can use to connect to Oracle 8i w/ more recent OJDBC jars.

2) I can have multiple OJDBC jars on my classpath so that I can use *ojdbc14.jar* on an exception basis and *ojdbc6.jar* everywhere else.  The trick here, of course, is figuring out how to specify which jar the connection needs to use the "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" class from.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Just out of curiosity I implemented your second approach via isolated classloader. It seems to be working:

```
public class DriverWrapper implements Driver {
    private Driver target;
    private String fakePrefix;
    private String realPrefix;

    protected DriverWrapper(Driver target, String  fakePrefix, String realPrefix) {
        this.target = target;
        this.fakePrefix = fakePrefix;
        this.realPrefix = realPrefix;
    }

    public static void loadDriver(URL[] classPath, String className, String fakePrefix, String actualPrefix) 
        throws Exception{

        URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classPath, DriverWrapper.class.getClassLoader());
        Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className);        

        // It's rather rude, but we haven't access to the existing instance anyway
        Driver d = (Driver) c.newInstance();
        Driver w = new DriverWrapper(d, fakePrefix, actualPrefix);

        // We don't care about already registerd instance, 
        // because driver loaded in isolated classloader 
        // is not visible to the rest of application, see DriverManager javadoc
        DriverManager.registerDriver(w);
    }

    private String resolveURL(String url) {
        if (url.startsWith(fakePrefix)) {
            return realPrefix + url.substring(fakePrefix.length());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean acceptsURL(String url) throws SQLException {
        url = resolveURL(url);
        if (url == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return target.acceptsURL(url);
        }
    }

    public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException  {
        url = resolveURL(url);
        if (url == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return target.connect(url, info);
        }
    }

    public int getMajorVersion() {
        return target.getMajorVersion();
    }

    public int getMinorVersion() {
        return target.getMinorVersion();
    }

    public DriverPropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException  {
        return target.getPropertyInfo(url, info);
    }

    public boolean jdbcCompliant() {
        return target.jdbcCompliant();
    }

}
```

Used as follows (driver jars shouldn't be located in the main classpath):

```
DriverWrapper.loadDriver(new URL[] { new File("ojdbc5.jar").toURL() }, 
    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle5", "jdbc:oracle");   
DriverWrapper.loadDriver(new URL[] { new File("ojdbc14.jar").toURL() }, 
    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle14", "jdbc:oracle");

... DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle14:...", ...);
... DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle5:...", ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try next chance I get!

Comment: Geez I was going to implement the same thing in a few days, many thanks to share this code with us.